# Angular Dynamic Environment API replacement

Tags: angular

I have a simple application with login page. On this page there is login, password and extra dropdownlist field where user choose to which API he would like to connect.

In code I have environments.ts file with apiEndpoint property and it's a string.

Example:

```
export const environment: any = {
  settings: {
    apiEndpoint: 'http://example.com/API1'
  }
}
```

This apiEndpoint is used in all services in the application.

I would like to change this value in envitonments.ts dynamically. So when the user choose on login page from dropdownlist '**API2**' then environments.ts looks like:

```
export const environment: any = {
  settings: {
    apiEndpoint: 'http://example.com/API2'
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for saving such information in the environment? Moreover when you want to do something dynamically there is no point to use environment variables

Comment: @Sergey So how to do it without environment variables?

Comment: You may create a singleton service which will have a set of APIs and currently chosen API.

Answer (score 0):

your environment should be like this:

```
export const environment = {
   production: false,
   API1: 'https://example.com/api1',
   API2: 'https://example.com/api2'
};
```

and when you choosing an option from your select box call one of these APIs.

Comment: So I have to save somehow user choice? Should i do it using localstorage?

Comment: if you want to save it for a long time localStorate is a good choice but if you want to clear it after exiting from the browser you can use session storage is a better idea.